# getting date from datetime data

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime data in this format,

```
08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00
```

I need to extract only date,that is `12 03 2016` in python.

I have tried

```
datetime_object=datetime.strptime('08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00','%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y')
```

I get an

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  +0000 GMT+00:00
```

Comment: if you need it as string then use slicing `[13:23]` - `'08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'[13:23]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this as string then use slicing

```
text = '08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'

print(text[13:23])

# 12 03 2016
```

but you can also convert to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

text = '08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(text[13:23],'%d %m %Y')

print(datetime_object)
# datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 12, 0, 0)
```

---

**BTW:**

in your oryginal version you have to remove `+0000 GMT+00:00` usinig slicing `[:-16]`

```
strptime('08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'[:-16], '%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y')
```

---

You can also use `split()` and `join()`

```
>>> x = '08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'.split()
['08:15:54:012', '12', '03', '2016', '+0000', 'GMT+00:00']

>>> x[1:4]
['12', '03', '2016']

>>> ' '.join(x[1:4])
'12 03 2016'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an external library, I find the [dateparser module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) much more intuitive than pythons internal datetime.  It can parse pretty much anything if you just do

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00')
```

It claims it can handle timezone offsets tho I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
d = '08:15:54:012 12 03 2016 +0000 GMT+00:00'
d = d[:23] #Remove the timezone details

from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime(d, "%H:%M:%S:%f %m %d %Y") #parse the string
d.strftime('%m %d %Y') #format the string
```

You get:

```
'12 03 2016'
```